# Can Human Verification sensitivity be turned down?

Tags: feature-request

I'm editing the formatting on the answers this question: [What are the tools that every Do-it-Yourselfer must own?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/53/tools-that-every-do-it-yourselfer-must-own/) and I keep getting asked to verify that I'm human. I completely understand the need for this check, but it asks me every other time I submit - could the verification not be made less frequent the more times I pass it successfully in a session?

I guess perhaps this is something that reduces when you get to moderator level? Perhaps I need to do something more useful on the site than formatting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're getting this, you are editing too rapidly. To reduce the incidence of captcha, edit a bit more slowly -- shall we say a bit more human-like? :)

Comment: I guess if I was a moderator or something then I wouldn't get this? I was doing moderator-like editing - lots of small format / spelling tweaks on posts...

Answer (score 0):

I believe once you pass it quite a few times it will become less of a nuisance. I had it ask me for verification about 30 times yesterday. It is pretty annoying though.